# How to make YouTube API Calls from GWT App

Tags: gwt, youtube-api

I need to integrate YouTube API into my GWT web application.  I need to make **YouTube API calls** such as the following:

- **UPLOAD:** https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading
- **CHECK STATUS:** https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_checking_video_status
- **SET DEVELOPER TAGS:** https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos#Assigning_Developer_Tags

In order to circumvent browser's **same origin restrictions**, the calls have to be **CORS** calls.

How can I make these **YouTube API calls** from my **GWT web application**?  A small code sample would be greatly appreciated.

*Note that I have tried using **YouTube Direct Lite**, but it seems it doesn't allow setting **developer tags**, which is **crucial** for me.*

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: As stated above, I have tried YT Direct Lite API.  Additionally, I have tried making CORS calls from GWT client-side, but to no avail.  Thus, I ask those with experience in the area whether they were successful and to share their code if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube has provided a sample showing how YouTube API CORS calls should be made:

- [Source code for the sample](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/trunk/gdata/youtube_upload_cors.html?r=246)
- [Demo of the sample](http://gdata-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gdata/youtube_upload_cors.html)

You can integrate the JavaScript from the sample into your GWT app using GWT's JavaScript Native Interface (JSNI):

- [More information on JSNI](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI)

Note that the sample JavaScript uses [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) which is not supported by some browser versions:

- [CORS/`XMLHttpRequest` support matrix](http://caniuse.com/cors)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the YouTube API personally, but from what I can deduce from the API, you essentially need to accomplish three things

1. Make HTTP POST request calls via [RequestBuilder](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html) in GWT as outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideHttpRequests)
2. [Create and parse through XML](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsXML)
3. Make use of [FormPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html) with a [FileUpload](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FileUpload.html) Widget to handle the actual file upload

What I linked, which provides some good code examples, should certainly help you make the API calls in GWT as required by YouTube. To make the HTTP calls CORS, see [this SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910185/making-cross-site-asynchronous-http-post-from-gwt-client)